# Unexpected localeCompare Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few lines of code that attempt to detect the last field that the user interacted (typed) with.

The following event handler functions correctly, but the first case of the `if/else` always runs regardless if the user input text into field `#input1` or `#input2`. Is there an unexpected behavior of localeCompare in this example?

**JS:**

```
$("#input1, #input2").keyup(function () {
    if (("input1").localeCompare($(this).attr("id"))) {
        calculateA();
    } else if (("input2").localeCompare($(this).attr("id"))) {
        calculateD();
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="input1">
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"></span>
        <input id="foo" class="span7" type="text">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"></span>
        <input id="bar" class="span7" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** It turns out that the error was not entirely on account of the code posted above. The two comparisons in the `.js` snippet were actually the body of a `setTimeout` callback function; as such, I did not realize that the execution context (and subsequently, the value of '`this`') would change!

Comment: Why don't you simply use !== ?

Comment: Your inputs have the IDs `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: @FelixKling Your approach with `event.target` might be in fact what OP was looking for, I didn't think about this one.

Comment: @dystroy: Maybe, but it wouldn't work either since he compares the ID against `"input1"`, which is the ID of the div, not the inputs. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: originally, I compared "foo" and "bar" to $(this).attr("id"), but it didn't work; console.log($(this).attr("id")) always returned either "input1" or "input2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) instead of `this`:

```
var id = event.target.id;
if (id === 'foo') { 
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: For some reason, I receive a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined" when I try to access the "id" field of event.target.

Comment: Oh, you haven't defined your event handler with a parameter. You need `$("#input1, #input2").keyup(function (event) {`. I think that's also explained in http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

You test can't never return `0`, because you don't have any input with id `input1`, and the div with this id won't be `this` when the `keyup` event is raised.

Supposing you give the id `input1` and `input2` to your inputs, your code is still too complex. You don't need `localeCompare` to test string equality. And I suspect you didn't get that the result pass as `true` in a `if` test when the strings are **different**. You seem to want

```
$("#input1, #input2").keyup(function() {
    if ("input1"===this.id) {
        calculateA();
    } else if ("input2"===this.id) {
        calculateD();
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any insight into why console.log($(this).attr("id")) always returns "input1" or "input2." Originally, the comparison utilized the ids of the input, but this didn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you bind on `$("#input1, #input2")`, `this` can only be `#input1` or `#input2`.

Comment: I did not know that! I assumed that since the event handler could be triggered by a descendant element, $(this) would refer to the specific caller.

Comment: @cardinal19821: I recommend to read http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.